# Access denied for aws public sagemaker xgboost registry

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-ecr

I am trying to pull a prebuilt xgboost image from the public aws xgboost registry specified here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/ecr-us-west-2.html#xgboost-us-west-2.title, however whenever I run the sagemaker pipeline I get the error:

```
ClientError: Failed to invoke sagemaker:CreateModelPackage. 
Error Details: Access denied for registry ID: 246618743249, repository name: sagemaker-xgboost. 
Please check if your ECR image exists and has proper pull permissions for SageMaker.
```

Here is the attached role boundary I am using to run the pipeline:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "codebuild:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "codepipeline:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "events:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/ml-*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "ecr:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ecr:us-west-2:246618743249:repository/246618743249.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/sagemaker-xgboost:1.0-1"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

and below is the attached policies for the role:

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "ecr:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Sid": ""
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

plus the AWSCodePipelineFullAccess, AWSCodeBuildAdminAccess, and AmazonSageMakerFullAccess managed policies.

Why can't I access the image/why am I getting this error? As you can see I gave my role full permissions for the ecr registry in the boundary, and full permissions for ecr in the attached policy.

Comment: the ARN in your role boundary looks wrongly formatted. It should be `arn:aws:ecr:us-west-2:246618743249:repository/sagemaker-xgboost:1.0-1` (see [resource-arn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonelasticcontainerregistry.html#:~:text=arn%3A%24%7BPartition%7D%3Aecr%3A%24%7BRegion%7D%3A%24%7BAccount%7D%3Arepository/%24%7BRepositoryName%7D))

Comment: no tags allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the boundary to be this:  `arn:aws:ecr:us-west-2:246618743249:repository/sagemaker-xgboost`